# Is there ever a need to allocate a single int dynamically?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

One example of dynamic allocation on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) is:

```
int* p1 = new int;
```

Is there ever a need to allocate a single int dynamically?

Comment: I'm going to go with **No**.

Comment: Except for example purposes I struggle to find any good reason.

Comment: I think it is difficult to speak for every potential programming problem. Even if you can't think of one now, you never know when it might be an appropriate solution.

Comment: I the old days, a counter for a shared resource. In the modern era you'd use a shared pointer for that job.

Comment: Not on purpose would you do that.  Maybe in a template, and the template type is `int`, and the template code happens to do `new T;`.  But even that should be rare, given `<type_traits>`

Comment: @user4581301 Could you please elaborate on the old days example or point me to further reading?

Comment: Take a look at `std::shared_ptr`. Now-a-days we have we'd use it, but in the old days you'd have to roll your own. At the guts there is a counter that keeps track of how many owners there are. When the counter hits zero, the referenced object is destroyed. All holders of the shared pointer must operate off of the same counter, so they have, in addition to a pointer to the shared object, a pointer to a shared  integer to keep count.

Comment: The only real world use case I can imagine would be to test whether a (freestanding) environment allows for dynamic allocation. According to the standard, compiler defined constants should declare that, but many of us have used environments taking liberalities with the standard.

Answer (score 1):

When all integral values are valid in your application's logic, using an `int*` adds the additional `NULL` value. This is useful when, for example, you are dealing with a NULLABLE database column of type int.

Additionally, on 16-bit systems, `int` operations weren't atomic, so updating an `int` value while reading it from another thread isn't a threadsafe operation, but sharing an `int*` is.

(Yeah, I'm stretching here, but I have used both in the past)

Comment: you could use a `std::optional<int>` in that case

Comment: and I would for a c++11 question

Comment: @Shloim FWIW, the C++ tag means the current standard of C++, which right now is C++17.

Comment: we have 2020 now, c++11 is not the current standard anymore. Anyhow `std::optional` is c++17

Comment: Sorry, It didn't say so in the tag description. Maybe someone should edit it.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 When you say "We have 2020 now", do you mean "We have C++20 now" (which is not yet true, but it probably will be later this year), or do you mean "It is 2020 now" (which is true, but is a very different statement)

Comment: BTW, using a pointer and using a dynamic allocated int are different things. I have often used pointers on automatic int variables...

Comment: @MartinBonner i meant the year 2020, where support for C++11 is widely available. Since 0x i dont believe in a 1-to-1 relation between year and version of the c++ standard anymore ;)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 C++11, +14, and +17 adhered to the timescales.  C++20 is on schedule too (Committee Draft was distributed in July,  comments were acted on in November, they expect to have the final draft in February, and then it's just a matter of getting the National Standards bodies to vote for it.)